# What limits the maximum number of nodes of a RS422 bus? How to check if N>10 nodes is possible without repeater?

Tags: analog, communication, digital-communications, bus, rs422

I have 13 identical devices which communicate with a host via RS422. None of them are addressable (they assume point-to-point connection).

I would like to string them in a RS422 bus. I thought of using relays and Chip Select signals to switch the TX+/- lines of the devices, however I am still facing the "maximum 10 nodes" limitation of the RS422 standard.

I read the limitation to 10 nodes may be extended on a case-by-case basis, but what does this limit depend on and how can I check my 13 devices may comply to the RS422 standard?

I need the full reliability of the standard, so I cannot "just test and see if it works".

P.S: For your information, the devices used are [Maxon ENX EASY quadrature encoders](https://www.maxongroup.com/medias/sys_master/root/8836894752798/enx-easy-en-Nov-11.pdf) with RS422 tranceivers implementing the SSI2 protocol.

Comment: Pick an RS422 chip and see what it says it can deliver in terms of nodes. Or use RS485.

Comment: Although this certainly works (can any RS485 transceiver drive these RS422 chips right out of the box?), could you answer the question? I would like to understand this limitation.

Comment: One limitation: The differential receivers usually have a weak pull-up and pull-down on each input. The voltage divider is slightly different on the plus and minus inputs to guarantee a specific logic level on the output when the inputs are disconnected. Too many receivers in parallel will eventually load down the bus.

Comment: Make them all RS485 was my suggestion but I guess you can't modify the master.

Comment: I may be able to modify the master for a RS485 master (though the question still stands). @Mattman944: could you expand with a schematic in an answer?

Comment: The encoder clock inputs have 132 ohm RS422 termination. No RS422 driver can drive the clock to more than one encoder at a time. Also the encoders have RS422 outputs so they can't be tied together. So basically you don't have to worry about having max 10 listeners on the bus because you can't drive more than one terminated bus. And there must only be one transmitter on bus.

Comment: @Justme: RS422 is supposed to be multi-drop, so TX+/- lines of RS422 devices should be able to be tied together? (I have seen schematics which makes this explicit)

Comment: If someone could find a RS422 or RS485 chip for the master and explain based on technical details of the datasheet why it is suitable for this application, I think it would be very informative and it would answer the question.

Comment: @MisterMystère It is possible, under certain conditions. There are at least two issues. Connecting RS-422 driver outputs together requires that the output drivers are enabled only one at a time. Can you be sure that these encoders disable their output drivers when idle, and only enable when being clocked? If manual does not say it supports multi-drop, then it doesn't. Also, since one RS-422 transmitter only supports singly terminated bus, so it means the driver should be at the other end of the bus, not in the middle, so it basically is meant to have only one transmitter at one end of the bus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the standard defines it, by specifying how much a single receiving unit can load the bus (with resistance and capacitance), and how much load on a singly-terminated bus a single driving unit must be able to drive. The numbers are just selected so that a standard driver can drive a singly-terminated bus with ten standard receivers. Sometimes modern receivers do not load down the bus so much so if it presents half a load then you can have 20 half-loading receivers.

Also the wiring capacitance and resistance loads the bus, so long wires limit the number of receivers too. To calculate this you need to know the capacitance of the wire.

But that only applies to the RS-422 drivers drivers and buses.
Not to SSI encoder devices, that utilize RS-422 standard, and further define how they use the RS-422 signaling. As devices, they are meant to be connected so that there is one bus master, and one encoder, and you can't change that.

Your encoder already incorporates a RS-422 receiver for the clock bus, and since the encoder is meant to be the single receiver at the end of a bus, it provides a termination resistor. So you cannot have multiple encoders connected to the clock bus, and no matter how you multiplex the bus to many encoders, the encoder has to be at the end of the bus wire.

Also the encoders have RS-422 transmitters for the data. They are always active, driving the bus - at least no SSI bus application note says otherwise. With RS-422, only one transmitter can be active at one time, and the transmitter must also be at the start of the bus to avoid signal reflections from stubs.

So clearly, the SSI encoders are point-to-point devices meant to be on the end of the bus, not in the middle.

If you do use for example relays to mux between encoders, either you have to have the relays at the master end, and from each relay you run a cable to each encoder. If you want to have one chain of encoders, you have to have a relay at each encoder to select if the bus goes to this encoder or if the bus continues to the next relay.

Comment: Very interesting answer, many thanks (+1). I just do not get why you say I cannot exploit multi drop for the clock signal, at least - all receivers have to be terminated by a resistance corresponding to the transmission line to avoid reflections (due to high input impedance differential amplifiers), right? So in theory I could get the RS422 clock to 10 of these encoders and deal differently with the DATA out, correct?

Comment: A transmitter can drive ten devices with one termination. It can't drive more than one termination, so it can't drive more than one encoder.

Comment: What I am saying is how come it is expected that several receivers can be connected to one transmitter, with only one termination resistor? All the receivers which do not have termination resistors will generate reflections from the high impedance of the differential stage?

Comment: The termination must be at the end of the bus. Encoders are along the bus, without stubs, so there are no reflections.

Comment: Ah, right, that makes sense. Thanks!